# react three fiber white canvas when navigate to page use model

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

Im working on a react three fiber project and get a problem I have a home page with a button when click it will navigate to the page use 3d model.the problem is when navigate there is a white screen for like 0.5s and then show the model, i use useNavigate() from react router dom to navigate and the model size is about 13mb here is some code

```
 export const Model = (props) {
 const { nodes, materials, scene } = useGLTF("./models/the_vast_land.glb");

  scene.traverse((child) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    if (child.isMesh && child.material.map) {
      // @ts-ignore
      child.material.map.encoding = THREE.LinearSRGBColorSpace;
      // @ts-ignore
      child.material.map.needsUpdate = true; // Ensure the changes take effect
    }
  });
return (..... code that generated by npx gltfjsx command);
}
useGLTF.preload("./models/the_vast_land.glb");
```

I use the suspense and find the white screen is not the loading page and there some warning
from threejs in the console  like "VM42:8 THREE.ImageUtils.getDataURL: Image converted to jpg for performance reasons"
dose anyone Know how to fix it.